# Play sound when binding updates

Tags: wpf, audio

hallo I want to play wav file in my WPF application when app detects disconnect from network. I am using MVVM pattern and PRISM. What I want to achieve is when my Viewmodel receives Event published by EventAggregator it sets some property to bool. I want to e able to listen to this property change from XAML and play sound based on its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to use System.Media Namespace SoundPlayer or MediaPlayer to play sounds based on Event Trigger in View Model

Eg:

```
readonly SoundPlayer _alertBeep = new SoundPlayer("FilePath");
private MediaPlayer _laserBeep = new MediaPlayer("FilePath");
```

SoundPlayer has option to only play / stop. But MediaPlayer is extended to have more controlling options.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a converter that passes on the value as is and plays a sound with a MediaPlayer. That way, you could attach it to a specific binding instead of the view model.